# Pointers and const in C++

Tags: c++, constants

When dealing with pointers and const, I see there are three ways to declare them:

1)

```
int nValue = 5;
int *const pnPtr = &nValue;
```

2)

```
int nValue = 5;
const int *pnPtr = &nValue;
```

3)

```
const int 5;
const int *const pnPtr = &nValue;
```

Example 1 is referred to as "Const pointer to non-const". The address cannot change but the value can change. So we can do something like the following, since nValue in example 1 is a non-const int:

```
int nValue = 5;
int const *pnPtr = &nValue;

*pnPtr = 6;
```

But we cannot do the following in example 1:

```
int nValue = 5;
int nValue2 = 6;
int const *pnPtr = &nValue;
pnPtr = &nValue2;
```

Example 2 is referred to as "Pointer to const". This means that the address can change, but the value cannot. We can do the following:

```
int nValue = 5;
int nValue2 = 6;

const int *pnPtr = &nValue;
pnPtr = &nValue2;
```

But we cannot do the following in Example 2:

```
int nValue = 5;
int nValue2 = 6;

const int *pnPtr = &nValue;
*pnPtr = nValue2;
```

Example 3 is a "Const pointer to const". This means neither address or value can change:

```
const int nValue;
const int *const pnPtr = &nValue;
```

My question is related to the second example. Why is the second example called a " Pointer to const" when nValue is not a const. It is a regular int declaration. Also, in the second example, what if when we assign it another address, that other address has a different value, can't we just deference that address, and therefore return the different value? Wouldn't that defeat the whole purpose?

Comment: There are 4 ways to declare pointers, see Dietmar Kuhl's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `const` in the second example applies to the `int`, i.e. you have a non-`const` pointer to a `const int`. Since types in C and C++ are read right to left, it is actually easiest to put the `const` always to right. It is also the only place where it can be put consistently:

```
int i(0);
int      *       p0(&i); // non-const pointer to non-const int
int const*       p1(&i); // non-const pointer to const int
int      * const p2(&i); // const pointer to non-const int
int const* const p3(&i); // const pointer to const int
```

That is, you can apply `const` to the pointer (`p0` and `p1` can be changed but `p2` and `p3` cannot) as well as to the entity the pointer points to (`*p0` and `*p2` can be changed but `*p1` and `*p3` cannot be changed). For the second and the forth line, you could swap the `int` and the `const` but I'd advise against do so.

Answer (score 0):

In C even integer is not constant but we are declaring our pointer as we are dealing with the constant integer. in this case C implicitly convert that integer to constant when assigning it reference to pointer.

Usually we do this when passing some values to function where we can avoid some unexpected change.